# JQuery/Javascript Clear/Reset Drop down List to original values

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, drop-down-menu

Ok dokey, got a bit of jquery up and running, lovely stuff.

```
  
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $inputs = $("#tbxProdAC, #ddlBuyer, #txtbxHowMany, radTopx");
    $.each($inputs, function() { 
        $(this).focus(function() { 
              $.each($inputs, function() { 
                  $(this).val('');
                  $(this).attr('checked', false); 
              }) 
        }); 
    }) 
});
```

However, in my drop down list, I wish to retain the orignal value rather than clear it altogether.

Is there a way I can specify the individual values i.e. tbxProdAC ='', ddlBuyer = Original Value, txtbxHowMany='', radTopx =unchecked, etc?

Comment: please, edit your code, it's really messy :/

Comment: Sorry about that onodrowan..I was being dense and should have used the html properly!

Comment: i don't get it too, which of those elements is the select box? all those elements you specified seems to be checkboxes.

Comment: Hello Paulo. Essentially I have three searches going on in one page. A textbox search (tbxProdAC) a dropdownlist (ddlBuyer) and a textbox/radio button list. What I am trying to achieve is a process whereby if a user selects one of these searches, the content of the others is cleared i.e. essentially removing the need for a general "Reset all" button or equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tryed:

```
document.getElementById('formId').reset();
```

try it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#tbxProdAC, #ddlBuyer, #txtbxHowMany, radTopx").focus(function() { 
              document.getElementById('formId').reset(); 
        }); 
});
```

Comment: Hello TeKapa

I tried your method above but on the "document.getElementById('formId').reset();" line I get an error - "is null or or not an object."

Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: Sorry - I was being a tool and still left that line in i.e. document.getElementById('formId').reset();

That has worked a dream...thank you very very much.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to go through each one separately to do that.

i.e.

```
$('#tbxProcAC').val('');
$('#ddlBuyer').val($('#ddlBuyer')[0].defaultValue);
$('#txtbxHowMany').val('');
$('#radTopx').attr('checked',false);
```

Perhaps the second line there may be of most intrest to you - it shows how to access the original 'default' value.

Comment if you've any questions, good luck!

Comment: Thanks Gausie - I am assuming just remove the original $(this).val(''); line and replace with your suggestion?

As you can probably tell, newbie here willing to learn but only being two weeks into knowing anything about creating a web app, I'm struggling with the amount to learn!

Comment: All you need is what I've given you! (with `$(document).ready(function() {`  and `}` wrapped around of course). Read about selectors on the jQuery site for more info (http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors). Also, could you mark mine as answered, if it helped you with the problem? I like rep :-)

Comment: `$('#ddlBuyer')[0].defaultValue` gives me `undefined` so `$('#ddlBuyer').val(undefined);` is the simplest way to reset dropdown ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data function in JQuery - you can store all the existing values and call them again when you need them

Answer (score 0):

in JQuery can  select  First  Option `<option value="0" > </option>` first option value  is  zero  and  text is empty.
now

```
$('#DropDown').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');

$('#DropDown')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

$('#DropDown')  ->  select dropdown

find('option:first') -> find  first  option

attr('selected', 'selected') -> set attribute  selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way

```
 document.getElementById(‘drpFruits’).options.length=0;
```